# Update Access From Excel Userfor

Tags: excel, vba

I am having difficulties trying to figure why this code will not work.  What i am trying to do is update a access DB where to values are matched, but for some reason i cannot get it to read userform label captions.

Here is the code below, thanks in advance

```
Sub UpdateAccessDatabase()
Dim accApp As Object
Dim SQL As String
Dim id As Integer
Dim Var1 as Integer
id = frmsetup.update.Caption
var1 = frmsetup.lbldate.caption
SQL = "UPDATE [Table3] SET [Table3].Time_out= " & "Now()" & " WHERE [Table3].Sequence=" & id & " AND [Table3].Audit_Date=" & var1 & ""
Set accApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
With accApp
.OpenCurrentDatabase "\\*****\Visitor_Info\Visitor_Info.accdb"
.DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
.Quit
End With
Set accApp = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: a `.Caption` is usually text based ... try `id  = CInt(frmsetup.update.Caption)` and the same for `var1`

Comment: I keep recieving Type Mismatch error 13..stops and highlights id-.....

Comment: what was the error you were getting before you made the change I suggested? And what are the data types for `Sequence` and `Audit_Date` in the database?

Comment: same error, when it debug the hightlihted portion shows the value for some reason

Comment: dim `id` and `var1` as String and it will fixe those two lines ... however, your SQL may not work depending on the data types of `Sequence` and `AuditDate`

Comment: in that case, see the answer I am about to submit ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have `id` and `var` dimensioned as `Integer` and you are trying to pass `string` values to them by using the `.Caption` of the label on the userform. That is why you get the `Data Mismatch` error.

Do this:

```
Dim id As String
Dim Var1 as String
id = frmsetup.update.Caption
var1 = frmsetup.lbldate.caption
```

Then you may need to adjust your SQL to ensure access can read it probably, by placing single quotes around your string variables. That would like this:

```
SQL = "UPDATE [Table3] SET [Table3].Time_out= " & "Now()" & " WHERE [Table3].Sequence='" & id & "' AND [Table3].Audit_Date='" & var1 & "';"
```

Also, note that I added the semi-colon to the end of the SQL statement, which Access needs to recognize it as the end of the SQL.

Comment: That worked like a charm, thanks so much, would i use integer if i was to define var="Hello" Just trying to understand..Thanks so much tried all day should have come to here first..too stubburn iguess..lol, Thanks

Comment: glad it worked. Please mark as answered if so. Integer variable types are only for numbers between ~32,000 (neg and pos). String variables are for text. It would be good to read up on variable types and their uses. :)